# Unable to compile Dynamic Html using $compile

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dynamic-html

I am trying to add dynamic html to my code using below lines

```
var el = $compile('<a ng-controller=\"tableController\" ng-click=\"open\">...ReadMore</a>')($scope);
```

However it is producing the below error
[image]

Can anyone help?

Comment: $compile(str)($scope); This is the syntax you have written. Could you tell me that your controller js is already loaded?

Comment: Just try to use a simple string <a>...ReadMore</a>  Is it ok?

Comment: i need ng-click directive to capture the click event

Comment: For test cases, compile the string <a>...ReadMore</a>, Let me know is it ok?

Comment: @Shohel yes compiling just the string <a> produces no error

Comment: Good, You have a problem of the controller, Now add a controller to your string, and test again, If you get the error, then check the controller code, is it right or not,

Comment: Ensure your contoller js is loaded

Comment: so i did remove the ngcontroller attribute since it was mentioned in the parent node and not required.However i am not getting any errror.But ng-click is not working

Comment: @Shohel thank you for the help.I was able to solve the problem

Comment: You need to add open() , missed parentheses

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188788/discussion-between-shohel-and-neehu).

Comment: hi shohel sure i have some more queries can we continue over chat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the parentheses of the open method, The following code should be work.

```
var el = $compile('<a ng-controller=\"tableController\" ng click=\"open()\">...ReadMore</a>')($scope);
```